# Why won't Wordpress hosted on Google Cloud Platform send email?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, wordpress, mx-record

I have installed wordpress on google cloud platform. The domain name already existed. The installation is successful however impossible to receive emails from the site contact form.
I tried several mail without success.
I also wanted to add a wordpress user but the person does not receive the invitation email.

How to configure to receive the mail?

I have however entered the MX parameters of google domain (gsuite)

Answer (score 0):

Virtual machines in Google Cloud Platform cannot send email through normal SMTP on port 25. You have to set up your machine to relay mail (on authenticated port 587, or otherwise) through a third party email provider. Google provides more information on [how to do this with common third party providers](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail).

Answer (score 0):

Following the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail), that was already shared, you could use third party services.
I'm sharing you 2 option you could try with the guides to configure it:

You could use sendgrid, with this [guide](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/getting_started_smtp.html) or smtp2go, and here the [guide](https://support.smtp2go.com/hc/en-gb/articles/223087627-SMTP-Settings) with the instructions.

You could us the next [guide](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/use-smtp/) to configure the SMTP to send emails from wordpress.